# how to make nginx proxy pass along connection refused?

Tags: nginx

I have an nginx proxy pointing at an external server.  When the external server is down, the nginx proxy returns a 502 bad gateway.

Instead, I'd like nginx to also refuse the connection - How can I do this?

Comment: this belongs on [sf]

Comment: How do you make this distinction?

Comment: its about "professional server configuration"

Comment: You can't. You have already accepted connection. The nearest thing you could do is to close connection without response